# Connect Xamarin Forms to SQL Server 2017 Management Studio using REST API

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, xamarin, xamarin.forms

so my team and I developed an app in Xamarin Forms cross-platform. Now we have also a database in SSMS 2017. For testing purposes I would like to send like a entry form with this fields:

Username: _____
ID#: _____
phone: ______

From my app I have to send this information to my database base that is already created with also those nodes. My actual app has more entry fields, but for now I'm just testing. I have done some research and the best option is to use a web service but I just don't know where to start from. Please help.

Comment: There are **thousands** of tutorials, walkthroughs and sample apps demonstrating how to create webservices.  For example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/data-cloud/web-services/

Comment: I've watched more than 30 tutorials today and they look similar to what I want to do but then they use either azure or it's more web app oriented.

Comment: @LuisDelgado: Did you got any solution or tutorial regarding same? I am also trying from best search but not getting perfect documentation step by step. Other which I am getting are too complicated for me as I am not knowing much about MVVM or MVC. Currently used direct connections and passing direct queries. Many have suggested to use API instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would write an API using Microsoft WebAPI 2.

Refer to this information...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: The thing is the database was created somewhere else and is not local. We have access as admins of our database but we have to access to it remotely. Also for firewall issues we can't use azure.

Comment: No need to use Azure. As long as you can query your remote DB then you are good to go. Your web API will just be your server side access to it from client applications

Comment: I can query my db, I've just seen so many ways to create a web API that I've got a little confused on how to start doing it. If you can provide me some code to start or website to check an example would be awesome...

Comment: This link from my above post...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api..... Will walk you through the whole process. Just replace their data sets (They mock them by just creating list) with your own by querying the DB for for your data

Comment: That link seems really helpful, I'm doing it right now. Just a quick question, since they used a fixed array for their demo, how would I code the query to send the data to my database?

Comment: I too have watched so many tutorials, but till yet so much confused where to start, how to start and which way to proceed further? Where to put our database login credentials in xamarin forms? Not a single video or walkthrough explains step by step coding and execution. Its part by part all and nothing integrated. If anyone have any still close to any such tutorial please post the link for quick understanding how to implement Web API in xamarin forms with a simple example would be highly appreciated.